# How to record multiple keydown events in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sveltekit

```
    on:keydown={(e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Control') {
            if(e.key ==='Backspace')
            ctrl_backspace();
        }
        else if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
    
            backspace();
        }
    }
```

I want to check if control and backspace both are pressed at the same time as well as check if the backspace is pressed once. Both the cases will call different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiers are included as separate properties of the event:

```js
if (e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && e.key == 'Backspace') {
  // ctrl + backspace
}
if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && e.key == 'Backspace') {
  // backspace
}
```

Would recommend also checking that the other modifiers are `false` for a precise match, the user might have tried to invoke something else otherwise.

There also is [a `metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey), which is relevant on Macs, representing Command. You might want to combine the state with `ctrlKey` for some normalization.